# Install 12.04 on top of existing Linux Mint installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

This question has been answered before in many places but I just need some confirmation with my specific setup. I have Linux Mint installed and I just want a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install to completely replace Mint. It's dual booted with Windows 7 and I want that to remain completely in tact.

Anyway, I'm currently running the Live CD installer. I've said I want to specify my own partitions and I'm at the following screen:

[image]

The list at the bottom expanded:

[image]

I confused by all the different partitions. Seems like I should just check the box beside `sda5`. But what about `sda6`? Do I just leave that alone?

Also just for confirmation, is the "right" way to replace Mint, or should I be deleting it first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, backup your /home folder. Once you format sda5 your home folder will be lost. All traces of Mint will be also gone, so there is no need to delete it first.

You can check the box next to sda5. It should be formatted ext4 and the mount point should be "/" (without quotes).

You can leave the swap partition alone. It is used as virtual memory and hibernation. Nothing permanent is stored there. Ubuntu will use it just like Mint.

The boot loader (GRUB) should be installed in sda (not sda1).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I will go ahead and do that now. Just one other question...what do I now select from the "Device for boot loader installation" list? Is it the first item from that list in the image I posted above?

Comment: You are welcome. The boot loader (GRUB) should be installed in sda (not sda1).

Comment: Thank you. I'm going for it now. If you never hear back from me it's safe to assume my laptop didn't survive.

Comment: laptop perhaps didn't survive, but did you? anyway, thanks for the info it is useful for me right now.

Comment: Sure, as i always do when I solve the problem. Just in this case, you were faster. I have the pc at work ;)