# How do I install Ubuntu 14.04 over a current Linux distrobution?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, mint

I recently wanted to try out Linux, and I selected Linux Mint.  Wrong choice.

Now, my hard drive partition wise is a mess, and Linux Mint 17.2 is SO glitchy for me, I just wanted Ubuntu.

Can anyone help me?  My laptop is a TOSHIBA Satellite C55-B B5200.

Comment: You do a fresh install from a LiveUSB/LiveCD/LiveDVD, is that not how you did it before?

Comment: This has been asked many times. [How to install Ubuntu, remove Mint and set up a separate home partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202586/how-to-install-ubuntu-remove-mint-and-set-up-a-separate-home-partition) | [Install 12.04 on top of existing Linux Mint installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184479/install-12-04-on-top-of-existing-linux-mint-installation)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a seperate `/home` partition, you can replace your Linux Mint partition and mount your old `/home` partition in your new Ubuntu install. Make sure NOT to format your `/home` partition when installing Ubuntu. If you do, your files are lost.

`/home` is intended as a partition for your personal files. If there are (configuration) files outside your `/home` partition that you want to keep, move them beforehand.

If you did not select to have a seperate `/home` partition, don't worry, here is a [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to help you with that. It involves moving your files to a seperate partition. After following these steps, replace your Mint install with a new Ubuntu install.

If you are not content on keeping your files, you can just install Ubuntu as normal.